# Advice about Using std::filesystem on embedded system

Tags: c++, c++17

This is a very general question, as I'm investigating the new (since C++17) std::filesystem for embedded system. As a matter of fact, I currently use file systems like [SPIFFS](https://github.com/pellepl/spiffs) and created my own `file` and
`dir` classes that mimic POSIX functions as much as possible.

Although my custom system works, I have a few questions:

- Is it possible to re implement `std::filesystem` in someway to adapt it to my own file system with its limitations? Or does it have to included in the library being used (for instance, we use Newlib)
- If it's indeed possible, would it make sense?
- besides the fact of making my code much more portable, what else do I gain from using std::filesystem instead of my custom classes?

Thank you very much for your insights.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad - there's a better chance you will get useful answers if you focus on any concrete problems you're facing. Like something that `std::filesystem` supports but is not available in SPIFFS.

Comment: By definition, if you’re implementing `std::filesystem`, you’re a standard library implementor.  So it doesn’t make sense to say “Could I do so *with* this existing library?”.  If there’s a C++ standard library for your platform that doesn’t supply `<filesystem>`, adding it sounds like a fine idea, but as much for the future as for your current application.

Comment: Thanks @DavisHerring and Martin,

I found some interesting stuff here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223929/c-standard-libraries-on-bare-metal/223931

Actually, this helps me reformulate my (broad) question: if my understanding is correct, my concern should be with Newlib (the C++ library i'm using) and not with C++ itself. So, I just need to implement core functions like `fopen()` and I'm good to go?

But then I still don't see how to handle some system-specifric limitations, like the maximum file name (and path) length ?

Comment: @IbrahimK.: Certain implementations of `std::filesystem`, like libstdc++’s, are largely in terms of POSIX APIs like `stat` and `readdir`.  The most likely obstacle (aside from compiling a complicated library that might use other parts of its own standard library) is handling of `/`, since SPIFFS doesn’t treat it specially.  Length limits are not much of an issue, since `ENAMETOOLONG` already exists.